# How to use model class to edit , destroy and get single value in laravel 8 resource controller?

Tags: laravel, controller, crud, laravel-8

I want to develop an API with Laravel 8 with resource controller.
Previously we used id parameter to edit, delete and get single value from the database. But now, here is given model class as a parameter in show, edit, update and destroy method.
How can I use this model class to perform crud operations without id parameter?
I know I’m on a misconception and I want to get a clear idea.

```
public function show(Food $food)
{
    //
}

public function edit(Food $food)
{
    //
}


public function update(Request $request, Food $food)
{
    //
}


public function destroy(Food $food)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a better way of retrieving your data.

Instead of writing:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    echo $id; // 12
    $food = Food::find($id); // your food instance with id 12
    echo $food->id; //12
}
```

You write:

```php
public function show(Food $food)
{
    $food; // your food instance with id 12
    echo $food->id; //12
}
```

Laravel will match the parameter name of your route with the argument name in your controller method declaration and will automatically gives you the correct `Food` instance.

Your routes should looks like this:

```php
Route::get('foods/{food}', [FoodController::class, 'show'])->name('foods.show');
// for each verbs (index, show, update...)
// the "food" parameter will be internally mapped 
// to the $food argument inside your controller methods declaration 

// or even simpler:

Route::resource('foods', FoodController::class);
// which will declare all routes for this resource
```

This is called implicit model binding. The documentation on this topic can be find here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding